# Open HTML page from Inno Setup post install Run section entry

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to turn these `[run]` entries into internet hyper-links instead?

```
Filename: "{win}\hh.exe"; \
Parameters: "{app}\CommunityTalks.chm::/CommunityTalks.htm"; \
WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
Flags: nowait postinstall runmaximized; \
Description: "{cm:ShowOverview}"

Filename: "{win}\hh.exe"; \
Parameters: "{app}\CommunityTalks.chm::/revisions.htm"; \
WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
Flags: nowait postinstall runmaximized; \
Description: "{cm:ViewChangeHistory}"
```

I have managed to update my `[icons]` section of the script for the same two items:

```
Name: "{group}\Public Talks Help"; \
Filename: "https://help-pts.publictalksoftware.co.uk/pts-overview.html"

Name: "{group}\Revision History"; \
Filename: "https://help-pts.publictalksoftware.co.uk/pts-revision-history.html"
```

But I can't work out what the `[run]` counterparts should look like.

---

### Update

So I tried:

```
// AJT v19.0.0 Display the Overview help topic (now uses online link)
Filename: "https://help-pts.publictalksoftware.co.uk/pts-overview.html"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall runmaximized; \
    Description: "{cm:ShowOverview}"

// AJT v19.0.0 Display the Revision History help topic (now uses online link)
Filename: "https://help-pts.publictalksoftware.co.uk/pts-revision-history.html"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall runmaximized; \
    Description: "{cm:ViewChangeHistory}"
```

And I encounter an error during install:

[image: HTML Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open a link, you need to use [`shellexec` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=shellexec).

```
Filename: "https://www.example.com/"; \
    Flags: shellexec postinstall runmaximized; \
    Description: "Show Overview"
```

With `shellexec`, [`nowait`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=nowait) is implicit, so I have removed it.

[`runmaximized`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=runmaximized) will probably have little effect, as the link will typically open in a new tab of an existing browser window.

---

*Note that when opening a link from an elevated (installer) process, there's often a concern that the browser starts elevated too, what can be a security issue. Brief testing shows that the `shellexec` runs browser non-elevated. But I cannot tell if it is reliable.*

*See this topic for other solutions:

[How to open a web site after uninstallation in non-elevated mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63614641/850848)*